# On save fabric canvas custom attribute lost sometimes

Tags: angular6, fabricjs

On update and save fabricjs lost its objects's custom attribute sometimes (Mostly after 2nd time update)

```
 ThisCanvas._objects = this.getItemToSave();
      this._HttpDataService
        .updateMimic(
          JSON.stringify({
            name: currentMimicValue.MIMICNAME,
            mimicobjects: csvObjList,
            data: ThisCanvas
          }),
          "UpdateCanvasJSON?mimicID=" + currentMimicValue.ID
        )
        .subscribe(
          apiData => {
            this.responseData = apiData;
          },
          error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
          },
          () => {
              console.log("Mimic Sucessfully saved.");
          }
        );
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expected and actual results.

Comment: Use [canvas#toObject](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toObject) with your custom attributes as parameter.